# wxPython: wx.Choice event EVT_CHOICE fires on app start but not on selection change

Tags: drop-down-menu, event-handling, wxwidgets, wxpython

I create a wx.Choice using the following class:

```
class LanguageSelector(wx.Choice):
"""Class for the creation of a language selector."""
def __init__(self, parent):
    """Create a language selector, default to current language and bind options to localisation methods."""
    super().__init__(parent=parent, choices=self.list_available_languages())

    self.SetSelection(self.FindString(loc.o))  # Set current language as default option.

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.on_choice())  # This is the problem.

def on_choice(self):
    print("on_choice was triggered. Selected item is: " + str(self.GetSelection()))
    selection = self.GetString(self.GetSelection())
    print("Converted selection is: " + selection)
    loc.change(selection)
```

Don't mind the "loc" item: it's something I use to handle localisation.
self.list_available_languages() is a static method that populates the Choice with items.

Now the problem: when I run the app, the print messages are printed immediately and show the default selection (which is something that I'd rather didn't happen, but it's not important), but then no event is ever fired when I try to select the various options in the Choice drop-down, regardless of which one I choose.

I'd prefer not having to use a button to catch the selection and do it right when the selection is changed. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what version of python and wxPython? What OS? Did you compile wxPython yourself, downloaded an official release from wxpython.org or installed it from the repository? And finally - can you reproduce it in the wxPython demo?

Comment: I have python 3.6 32-bit and the wxPython version is 4.0.0b2 which I installed with pip following the instructions on wxpython's website. I'm on Windows 10 and finally, I didn't try the demos. Franky I don't even know which version I should download since my OS is 64-bit but I have a 32-bit version of python.
The way I'm detecting the bug is by running the program through PyCharm, by the way.

Comment: I suspect this may be related so I'll report it here in case it helps identify the problem:
I went on developing another part of my code and I ended up using another Bind to an event, this time for wx.EVT_LISTBOX. Now again, judging by what happens, it appears the event is fired once automatically when the app is run (which obviously shouldn't happen) and never when I do what should trigger it: exactly what is also happening with my wx.EVT_CHOICE in the body of my question above.
What ever could be the cause here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking your handler instead of binding it. You must pass the *function* and not the result of calling this function to `Bind()`. Just remove the parentheses to fix this.